# Win32 creating windows 7 status flyouts

Tags: windows, winapi, flyout

I am trying to create a Windows 7 status flyout like notification in the bottom right hand corner of my desktop. Any guidelines on how to accomplish this using win32 (and without having to write a ton of code) are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .Net, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7853/NotifyWindow-A-different-MSN-Messenger-style-notif) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3285/TaskbarNotifier-a-skinnable-MSN-Messenger-like-pop) shows how to create custom flyouts quite easily (both use P/Invoke so they should be pretty easy to port to anything else), even more simply you can use [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Doing this from C or C++ you can either use [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#display_notification) for the simple ballons or a custom ([borderless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) window animated with [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a `WM_TIMER` for the fancier slide-up/fade-in style popups/notifications.